# JBPM 6 reward basic application error

Tags: jbpm

Please help...

I am getting below error while deploying reward basic JBPM 6 sample application. I did only changes in data source from H2 to MySQL.

00:35:13,610 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
00:35:13,657 INFO  [org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration] (MSC service thread 1-2) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: org.jbpm.domain
    ...]
00:35:13,757 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-2) MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."rewards-basic.war#org.jbpm.domain": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."rewards-basic.war#org.jbpm.domain": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1767) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_60]
Caused by: **org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Unable to read XML**
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:106)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.addXMLEntities(Ejb3Configuration.java:734)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:603)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:162)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.start(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: **org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory Nested exception: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory**
    at org.dom4j.io.SAXReader.read(SAXReader.java:484)
    at org.hibernate.internal.util.xml.MappingReader.readMappingDocument(MappingReader.java:76)
    ... 10 more

Comment: tried to restore with original H2 datasource and found same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be the version of dom4j that you have in your class path.
Make sure that you are deploying the correct version of the application for the application server that you are using.

Regards